# Is there optimal algorithm to find subset of rows, which sum lies within specified interval?

Tags: algorithm

I have a matrix, 40 rows and 8 columns, with non-negative float numbers, and there are 16 float thresholds:

```
S_min1, S_min2, ..., S_min8
S_max1, S_max2, ..., S_max8
```

I need to find subset of rows, such that:

- sum over the first column lies between `S_min1` and `S_max1`
- sum over the second column lies between `S_min2` and `S_max2`
- ...
- sum over the eighth column lies between `S_min8` and `S_max8`

Is there any way to avoid exhaustive algorithm? Because iterating through 10^12 combinations do not look so good.

Comment: Are there any further constraints? Such as, any of the sums to be maximal/minimal in value? Total sum or size of the subset largest/smallest? Do you need to find all subsets that satisfy the condition, or will any one subset do? Does the subset have to be contiguous?

Comment: I have additional target function depending on rows in subset, so I need to find all subsets satisfying conditions to calculate which subset does minimize this function. No, subset does not need to be contiguous (in that case problem would be much easier).

Comment: Basically, I need to find all subsets and transfer them to other part of code.

Comment: @TimmyB, If this is the case, your approach is futile. Consider a case, S_min=0, S_max=10000, and values in rows for corresponding column: (1,2,3,4,...,39,40). So, if you are to find all possible subsets such that S_min < sum(subset) < S_max, then, your answer set has to have 2^40 subsets anyway. Hence, exhaustive is the only way.

Comment: @vish4071 Not necessarily -- if the shape of the target function is known, you could use a sum's distance to the function's extremums in exactly the same way as you would be trying to maximize/minimize it. How viable this approach is depends on how complex the function/shape is, since comparing 8d distances may not be trivial

Comment: @blgt -- In that case, full knowledge of target function is needed to proceed any further. Without any givens, I still think exhaustive is the only way if he wants all the subsets as the input to the target. However, even if we use the lazy approach, all inputs need to be provided to the target function anyway, which makes it equally complex anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a task for [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

You define integer coefficients `0/1` for every row, their sum should be in range 1..40.

Then define unequalities using these coefficients with cell values and your thresholds.

```
  A[1,1]*R[1] + A[1,2]*R[2] +... + A[1,40]*R[40] > S_Min1
  A[1,1]*R[1] + A[1,2]*R[2] +... + A[1,40]*R[40] < S_Max1
  ...
```

Solve tasks for every coefficient sum with some available LP solver
*(perhaps there is a way to avoid looping through possible sums, but I don't know appropriate condition)*